# SQL import pipe delimited with some data fields that have have pipe in record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently using Bulk insert in SQL to import a pipe(|) delimited which is pretty straight forward.  My problem I am running into is sometimes there are records that include the pipe(|), which will then in return bulk insert breaks it up into two different records.  Below is an example

```
12343|First Name|Last Name| Address field|Location
63494|Second First Name|Second Last Name| Address Field with | in it |location
```

My example above, the second record, bulk insert will split the address field because it contains a |.  Are there any suggestions out that I could use to avoid problems like this?

Thanks

Comment: This is a common problem with any CSV type data (which this essentially is). The most common way it's dealt with is to have a character, such as double quotes, to identify the boundaries of strings. Then your string will be essentially "Some string with P|pes in it", and it knows to treat that whole thing as a string literal. Be sure to pick a quoting character that itself you don't expect to show up in the string

Comment: double quotes like a text qualifier or something to that effect?

Comment: Exactly. Hopefully you have some control over the format the data is output as. if you don't you should yell at whoever does to add in a text qualifier. Or change the delimiter to something more obscure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that control over the file.  I agree totally on the delimiter to be something obscure, I like to use something like <delim>.  I will ask to put in a request for a text qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem before and from my experience there's not much you can do during the import. Obviously if you have any control during the export process from the source you can handle the cleansing of the data at that point, buy most likely is not your case. One thing you can do at least to prevent failures during the import is to validate your input file before the batch insert like I did with a simple code like this:

```
    public class ValidateMigrationFile {

    private static final String REGEX = "^([^|]*\\|){50}[^|]*$";

    public static void testFile(String fileName) {

        int lineCounter = 1;
        int totalErrors = 0;

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            String line = null;

            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {

                // Validate the line is formatted correctly based on regular expressions                
                if (!line.matches(REGEX)){
                    System.out.println("Invalid format on line " + lineCounter + " (" + line + ")");
                    totalErrors++;
                }

                lineCounter++;
            }
            br.close();
            System.out.println("Total rows processed: " + --lineCounter);
            System.out.println("Total errors found: " + totalErrors);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can detect in advance if your file is well formed and detect exactly what lines have the problem.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome.  I will have to figure this part out to test the files before import.

Comment: Can you point me in the correct direction on how to get this to work  in Visual Studio.  Do I make a new class and just past the code and write a console readline for the name of the file?

Comment: Yes, you can just create your class and call it by passing the filename or just add a Main method and hardcode the filename in the call to testFile method. Also you'll need to check if the regular expression is valid as it is in Visual Studio (I think it should work), and don't forget to change the regular expression with the number of pipes you're expecting for each line (in my example is 50).

Comment: Is there other name spaces I should be using?  the BufferedReader could not be found.

Comment: Well, yes, my code is in Java, you have to figure out the equivalent classes for c# or whatever language you're using. It's basic IO so it shouldn't be too difficult. For example the equivalent in c# for BufferedReader would be StreamReader.